# how do I balance my binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree

I already have a working binary tree database.  Unfortunately, it needs to have the ability to balance itself.  I don't want to rewrite the whole thing, I just want to include a function that will balance the tree.  Any algorithms or ideas?

Comment: [Googling "how to balance a binary tree"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+balance+a+binary+tree) brings up plenty of results. Pick one.

Comment: It's not merely "binary tree", it's "binary *search* tree".

Comment: @ArunSaha:  Why do you say that?  The OP did not say that the elements were sorted.

Comment: @James McNellis: You are right, however I inferred that from OP's requirement to "balance" the tree. I can't think of any reason why BT may need to be balanced (what's the basis of rotation, etc.), unless it is a BST. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 2):

AVL and RedBlack trees are self balancing trees.
You can traverse your original tree and insert the nodes in these trees.
Afterwards you can keep the new tree and discard your original tree.

Comment: I think what the OP had in mind was to keep all his code and just add a function that balances his regular binary tree.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the Stanford [libavl](http://www.stanford.edu/~blp/avl/libavl.html/Step-3-in-AVL-Insertion.html) tutorial quite helpful.

Check out the examples in [AVL tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) wiki.

Also, try to play with the AVL tree animations available in the web, such as

- http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~goodrich/dsa/trees/avltree.html or
- http://www.strille.net/works/media_technology_projects/avl-tree_2001/ or
- http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~stan/csi2514/applets/avl/BT.html

Answer (score 1):

AVL and Red-Black trees are balanced binary trees. I have an implementation of AVL trees. Look [here](http://github.com/navaneeth/datastructures/blob/master/avl-tree/avl.c). It supports insertion and search. Deletion is not implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

look for balanced trees like avl red black